# React Router : Data fetched using axios doesn't save when navigating to new route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a React app using `react-router-dom` and fetching data from my Django Rest Framework back-end and once the data has been fetched, and I navigate to another link, the data saved to the `window` and saved internally inside state is deleted. How do I persist this data in the client?

Here is the code :

`Router`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthHeader from './authheader';
import { BlogData, BlogDetail } from '../components/blog';



export default class AuthRouter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            authtoken: '',
        }
    }

    handler = (token) => {
        this.setState({
            isLoggedIn: true,
            authtoken: token,
        })
    }
    /**
     * ! Render the Route props inside of the
     * ! BlogData component
     */

    render () {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    {/* <Header /> */}
                    {/* <Route path='/home' exact component={WrappedHorizontalLoginForm} /> */}
                    {/* <Route path='/about' exact component={AuthHeader} /> */}
                    <AuthHeader
                        action={this.handler}
                        token={this.state.isLoggedIn && this.state.authtoken}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path='/blog'
                        exact
                        render={(props) => <BlogData {...props}
                            token={this.state.isLoggedIn && this.state.authtoken}
                        />} />
                    <Route
                        path='/blog/:id'
                        exact
                        render={(props) => <BlogDetail {...props}
                            token={this.state.isLoggedIn && this.state.authtoken}
                        />} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

The `Authheader` component passes props down eventually to `LoginFormOrUserComponent` here :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { localhost, authtoken } from '../backendUrlConstants';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

export default class LoginFormOrUserComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            authtoken: null,
            username: '',
            password: '',
        }

        // if (this.props.token) {
        //     this.setState({ authtoken: this.props.token })
        //     this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
        // }
    }

    // componentDidMount (props) {
    //     if (this.props.token) {
    //         this.setState({ authtoken: this.props.token })
    //         this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
    //     }
    // }

    passAuthTokenToParentClass = () => {

        const { authtoken } = this.state;
        if (authtoken) {
            this.props.action(authtoken)
        }
    }

    handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ username: e.target.value })
    }

    handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        const username = this.state.username;
        const password = this.state.password;
        axios.post(`${localhost}${authtoken}`, { username, password })
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ authtoken: res.data.token })
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
                this.passAuthTokenToParentClass()
            })
        // TODO: Catch the error if the username and password
        // TODO: are incorrect.
    }

    renderLoginFormOrUserComponent = () => {
        if (this.state.isLoggedIn === false) {
            return <Form className="mr-auto" >
                <Form.Row>
                    <Col xs={4}>
                        <Form.Control placeholder="Username" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={4}>
                        <Form.Control placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} />
                    </Col>
                </Form.Row>
                <Button variant="dark" onClick={this.handleSubmit} >Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        }
        return <Button variant="dark" >Account</Button>
    }

    render () {

        return (
            this.renderLoginFormOrUserComponent()
        );
    }
}
```

And here are the `BlogData` and `BlogDetail` component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { localhost } from '../backendUrlConstants';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';


export class BlogData extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        }
    }

    getUrl () {
        return this.props.location.pathname
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        const uri = this.getUrl()
        axios.get(`${localhost}${uri}`)
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                this.setState({ data })
            })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <ul>
                {this.state.data.map(
                    data => <li key={data.id} >
                        <Link to={`/blog/${data.id}`} >{data.url}</Link>
                    </li>
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export class BlogDetail extends BlogData {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props)
        this.state = {
            blogObject: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        const uri = this.getUrl()
        axios.get(`${localhost}${uri}`)
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;
                this.setState({ blogObject: data })
            })
    }

    render () {

        const { blogObject } = this.state;
        return (
            <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }} >
                <Card.Img variant="top" src={blogObject.blog_picture_context} />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{blogObject.blog_name}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>{blogObject.blog_post}</Card.Text>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}
```

Also, for context here is the url of my localhost Django server :

```
export const localhost = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
export const login = '/api-auth/login/';
export const authtoken = '/authtoken/';
```

Once I get the data from my backend, I lose it once I navigate to another page. There is clearly something I am missing here.

Comment: You need to persist your data in local storage or any other persisting mechanism. JS runtime in browser is temporary. Once you reload the page or navigate to new url, everything is reloaded fresh, thus `window.whatever` is lost.

Comment: Would it be simpler to use the HashRouter library instead? To stop the page re-loads... @hackape

Comment: yeah, I suggest the same.

Comment: https://github.com/RasCarlito/axios-cache-adapter

Answer (score 1):

Using hooks you can easily pass data when navigating to a new URL / link that normally would refresh your state. No need to use local storage or anything like that.

As an example, I have an admin dashboard that has nested routes for users where I want the url for the user to be the user id and I want to pass the user id to the new url and be able to use it within the new component.

My nested routes file looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Index, SignIn, SignUp } from '../onepirate/';
import { Admin, Event, CheckoutPath, Profile, Tickets, CheckoutComplete } from '../screens/';
import AdminDashboard from '../components/admin/AdminDashboard';
import UserAccount from '../screens/admin/user-components/UserAccount'
import Users from '../screens/admin/Users';

const adminRoutes = {
    "/dashboard": () => <AdminDashboard />,
    "/events": () => <Event />,
    "/users": () => <Users />,
    "/users/:userId": ({ userId }) => <UserAccount userId={userId} />,
}

export default adminRoutes;
```

As you can see I am passing the user Id from the /users component and sending it through the route as a property. At the same time the user id will be dynamically laced in the URL.

Then you import your router to the component where the routes should be handled:

```
import { useRoutes, useRedirect, navigate } from 'hookrouter';
export default function Admin() {
    // this function allows your to redirect from one URL to another    
    useRedirect('/admin', '/admin/dashboard');

    return (
            <main className={classes.content}>
                <Container>
                    {router}
                </Container>
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then as an example to navigate from my users component to users/:userID

```
import { useRoutes, useRedirect, navigate } from 'hookrouter';

const User = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Container>
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-search"
          label="Search field"
          type="search"
          className={classes.textField}
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={props.search}
        />
        <Table className={classes.table}>
          <TableHead className={classes.tableHead}>
            <TableRow className={classes.tableHead}>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableHead} align="">Id</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableHead} align="">Email</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableHead} align="">First Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableHead} align="">Last Name</TableCell>
              <TableCell className={classes.tableHead} align="">Info</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {props.data.map((user, index) => (
              <TableRow key={index}>
                <TableCell align="right">{user.id}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{user.email}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{user.firstname}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{user.lastname}</TableCell>

     // be sure to pass the user id in the navigate() function

                <TableCell><AccountBoxIcon onClick={() => (navigate("/admin/users/" + user.id))}></AccountBoxIcon></TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>

        </Table>
      </Paper>
    </Container>
  )
}
export default User;
```

Then in UserAccount compontent was linked in our routes file and passed the user ID to, we can see the data passed by console logging the props in a useEffect (component will mount equivelent) hook.

// UserAccount Component:

```
useEffect(() => {
// userId we sent as prop through route
        console.log(props.userId);
// ... do cool things
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I used it immediately after seeing this post.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is the code for persisting the data in local storage.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { localhost, authtoken } from '../backendUrlConstants';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

export default class LoginFormOrUserComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            authtoken: null,
            username: '',
            password: '',
        }

        // if (this.props.token) {
        //     this.setState({ authtoken: this.props.token })
        //     this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
        // }
    }

    componentDidMount (props) {
        const storage = window.localStorage
        const status = storage.getItem('isLoggedIn')
        if (status) {
            this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
            this.setState({ authtoken: storage.getItem('token') })
        }
    }

    hanldeClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false })
        this.setState({ authtoken: null })
        const storage = window.localStorage
        storage.clear()
    }

    passAuthTokenToParentClass = () => {

        const { authtoken } = this.state;
        if (authtoken) {
            this.props.action(authtoken)
        }
    }

    handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ username: e.target.value })
    }

    handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        const storage = window.localStorage
        const username = this.state.username;
        const password = this.state.password;
        axios.post(`${localhost}${authtoken}`, { username, password })
            .then(res => {
                // ! persist the data in localstorage =>
                storage.setItem('token', res.data.token)
                storage.setItem('isLoggedIn', true)
                this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true })
                this.setState({ authtoken: res.data.token })
                console.log(storage)
            })
        // TODO: Catch the error if the username and password
        // TODO: are incorrect.
    }

    renderLoginFormOrUserComponent = () => {
        if (this.state.isLoggedIn === false) {
            return <Form className="mr-auto" >
                <Form.Row>
                    <Col xs={4}>
                        <Form.Control placeholder="Username" onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col xs={4}>
                        <Form.Control placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} />
                    </Col>
                </Form.Row>
                <Button variant="dark" onClick={this.handleSubmit} >Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        }
        return <Button variant="dark" onClick={this.hanldeClick} >Account</Button>
    }

    render () {

        return (
            this.renderLoginFormOrUserComponent()
        );
    }
}
'''

I also added a logout button to clear the data kept in `localStorage` when the user clicks the Account button.
```